# Incrementing index inside subscript operator

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a 'smart' optimization when I stumbled upon some weird behavior, so I created a minimal example to replicate it.

In the code below, I create an array and shift elements to the left, then print the array.
The code works exactly like one would expect.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[5]{0,1,2,3,4};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];            // Array becomes {1,2,3,4,4}
    }

    std::cout << "Printing array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << array[i];              // Prints {1,2,3,4, 4}
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Now, looking at the first `for` block, I thought I could spare one `i` increment.
So I tried to rewrite that block as follows:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4;)
    {
        array[i] = array[++i];          // Expected: array becomes {1,2,3,4,4}
    }
```

This does not work, however.
`i` *is* in fact updated, because the program does not loop, but the assignment does not go as expected and the terminal outputs `Printing array: 01234`.

Now, it might have been that the expression on the right is evaluated before the expression on the left, in which case this behavior would be explained.
However, I also tried the following reverse iteration:

```
    for (int i = 4; i > 0;)
    {
        array[--i] = array[i];          // Expected: array becomes {1,2,3,4,4}
    }
```

And it also outputs `Printing array: 01234`.

In both cases, I tried compiling in debug mode, in case it was some weird compiler optimization responsible for it, but the result was still the same.

Comment: Before C++17, `array[i] = array[++i];` is UB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) (the top answer addresses this specific case)

Comment: *"I was trying to make a 'smart' optimization"* Let compilers do those kind of optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to C++17, it is undefined behavior,

Since C++17, we have

[Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

> 20) In every simple assignment expression `E1=E2` and every compound assignment expression `E1@=E2`, every value computation and side-effect of `E2` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E1`.

So

```
array[i] = array[++i];
```

`array[++i]` is evaluated first, (incrementing so `i`)
`array[i]` is evaluated after, with `i` incremented.

So it is mostly equivalent to

```
++i;
array[i] = array[i]; // Noop
```

And for

```
array[--i] = array[i];
```

it is mostly equivalent to

```
array[i - 1] = array[i];
--i
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP wants `E1` to be sequenced first :)

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) in an expression is unspecified. Don't read and write from/to an object in the same expression. The offending lines are:

```
array[i] = array[++i];
```

and:

```
array[--i] = array[i];
```

This was changed in the C++17 standard and if you compiled with C++17 support, you would not invoke undefined behavior.